# How can I use ñ or Ñ?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to use 'ñ' but I can't, I've tried with:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

but it didn't work. Instead of 'ñ', I get other character.
I also tried with:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
with codecs.open('output', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   f.write(u"ñÑ")
```

and I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 896, in open
file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output'
```

Comment: Python has no `DidntWorkError`.

Comment: what tim here is trying to say is that you need to tell us what "it didn't work" means. did you get an error? did it just not write to the file? what's going on?

Comment: @CristianGonzalez, what version of Python are you using.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf, I'm using 2.7

Comment: Ah. Open your file in write mode, such that it gets created.

Comment: @wpercy I already put the errors, sorry.

Comment: You have to open the file in write mode via `'w'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an `encoding` issue. The `coding` header you included does work (and is necessary for the `ñ` character). Running the code produces this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output'
```

You're attempting to open a file named `output` for *reading*. You need to open the file *for writing*:

```
with codecs.open('output', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   f.write(u"ñÑ")
```

Note the `'w'` flag in `open()`.